# Why using null-conditional operator in nullable context breaks static analyzer?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types, null-conditional-operator

Why after using [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) in [nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) (`#nullable enable`
) the static analyzer shows [CS8602](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8602)#possible-dereference-of-null) warning?

```
var test = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine(test.Count); // Ok
Console.WriteLine(test?.Count);
Console.WriteLine(test.Count); // CS8602 - Dereference of a possibly null reference
```

Here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P9jd7Q).

Is the answer simply "not smart enough"? I don't know how could `test` become null after `?.`, can it?

---

Another thought, there is actually a missing warning:

> Remove unnecessary null-conditional check, test can NOT BE be null here! Don't you see? Read tooltips! On every variable!

Comment: You know more about your code than the analyzer does.  On the first `test.Count`, the analyzer sees that `test` cannot be null (as the result of it being initialized previously).  But, then you (the author) say `Console.WriteLine(test?.Count)`.  The analyzer looks at it and says "damn, it looks like the author thinks that `test` could be null" and believes you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis is trying to learn from your usage of the value. Consider this recently annotated (and presumably incorrectly annotated) code:

```cs
#nullable enable
public int M(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (s is null)
        i++;
    i += s.Length; // possible NullReferenceException!
    return i;
}
```

Here the `null` test is telling the analysis that you think the value could be null, even though the incoming reference type is `string` not `string?`.

It's the same in your code. The `?.Count` is a null check, which makes the code afterwards think the value could be null.

Looking at your example, it's obvious that it could never be null. Clearly the analysis could be taught to differentiate between our two examples.

This feels like something that would have been discussed on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn or https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang. If not, you could open an issue there to suggest an improvement to the compiler's analysis.