# Why do I get CS8601 null pointers warning even I do null check before

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a code piece below which creates an `IplImage` object from a camera and then creates a bitmap using this `iplImage`.

```
var iplImage = Globals.ActiveCamera.Acquisition?.IplImage?.ConvertTo(PixelFormatName.BGR8, ConversionMode.Fast);

if (iplImage == null)
{
    return;
}

frame = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt16(iplImage?.Width()), Convert.ToInt16(iplImage?.Height()), Convert.ToInt16(iplImage?.PixelFormat().CalculateStorageSizeOfPixels(iplImage.Width())), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, iplImage.Data());
```

Even, I check for `null` and return if it is. I still get warning `CS8601` when using `iplImage.Data()`.

I'm confused what I am missing at this point.

Comment: remove the "?" from `iplImage?.Width()` and `iplImage?.Height()`. If you still get a warning, make it `iplImage!.Width()`

Comment: Removing "?" worked. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why using null-conditional operator in nullable context breaks static analyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930012/why-using-null-conditional-operator-in-nullable-context-breaks-static-analyzer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion would be that the warning is because

```
Convert.ToInt16(iplImage?.Width())
```

has nullable *input* to `Convert.ToInt16`. But you know `iplImage` cannot be `null` here. So, make it `Convert.ToInt16(iplImage.Width())` and `Convert.ToInt16(iplImage.Height())` respective.

Comment: Yes, also `iplImage?.PixelFormat()` => `iplImage.PixelFormat()`.